# Symfony 2 Forms: store view data in array and restore condition later

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I try to implement form values save in session.

1) click on button "change category" on `page1`

2) store data in session

3) redirect to `page2`

4) perform some changes with this saved form data and update it in session

5) redirect back to `page1` and restore form values by values stored in session

```
$product = new Product;

$productType = new ProductType;
$form = $this->createForm($productType, $product);

//get values from session
$form_values_in_session = ...

if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->bind($request);

    // if click on change category button
    if ($request->request->get('category')) {
        $form_raw_values = $request->get($productType->getName());

        $form_values = array();
        foreach ($form_raw_values as $form_field_name => $form_field_value) {
            if ($form->has($form_field_name)) {
                $form_values[$form_field_name] = $form_field_value;
            }
        }

        // store this data in session
        // and redirect
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl();
    }

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // form submit
    }
} else if ($form_values_in_session) {
    $form->bind($form_values_in_session);
}
```

Work good, but problem is form is being validated just after `$form->bind($form_values_in_session);` call and i see form errors on page.

The right way to do this: call setters for `$product`, but in this case i need manually convert view data -> norm data -> model data. Such methods in `Form` class is private and i need to copypaste some code from methods Form::viewToNorm, Form::normToModel and so on.

Is there better way?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is form validation work only with root form. That mean i can bind data for form childrens

```
foreach ($form->all() as $name => $field) {
    if (isset($form_values_in_session[$name])) {
        $field->bind($form_values_in_session[$name]);
    }
}
```